# Jenkins Manage Nodes and Clouds in Google Kubernetes Engine Cluster

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am just started learning Jenkins deployment on Google Kubernetes engine. I was able to successfully deploy an application to my GKE instance. However, I couldn't figure out how to manage Nodes and Clouds.

Any tutorial or guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underlying idea behind nodes : Just one node may not be sufficient/effective to run multiple jobs so to distribute the load jobs are transferred to a different node to attain a good performance.

### Prerequisites

#1 : A instance (Lets’ say it DEV) which is hosting Jenkins (git, maven, Jenkins)

#2 : A instance (Let’s call it Slave) which will be used to serve as host machine  for our new node

> In this machine you need to have java installed
> A pass wordless connection should be established between two instances.
> To achieve it enable password authentication >generate key in main machine i.e., Dev machine and copy this key into Dev machine.
> Create a directory “workspace” in this machine (/home/Ubuntu/workspace)

Now Let's get started with Jenkins part -
Go to manage Jenkins> Manage nodes and cloud

> By default Jenkins contains only the master node

To create a new node one could use the option “new node” available on the right side of the screen.

> Provide a name to new node, mark it as permanent agent

Define remote root directory : It is the directory which is defined by you.

> For e.g., a location like
> “/home/Ubuntu/workspace “

Provide a label of your choice for e.g., let’s give the label as “Slave_lab”

> Label = slave_lab

Now define your Launch method

> Let’s select “Launch agent via execution of command on the master”

In the command put command as :

> Ssh Ubuntu@private_IP_of_slave java -jar slave.jar
> Note : here by @private_IP_of_slave i mean the IP of machine which will be used for our new node

Now we could process to configure jobs to be run on our new node

> For that right click on your job > select configure

Under the general tab select the following

> "Restrict where this project can be run" and provide the label "slave_lab"

Now when you’ll run the job it will be executed on the slave node not on the master name.

Comment: Multiple open source tutorials are available over YouTube. You could pick any as per your area of interest.

Comment: I hope if this was of help to you. If it answered your question, click the check mark to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped

Comment: Hi Abhishek. This was helpful. Also, if you could link to any detailed tutorial, that would be of great help as well.